# The mirror across the diagonal of a non-square matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Given a non-square, mx2 matrix in Matlab, where the row dimension varies (it varies because it runs within a for loop storing the results of some calculation I am making) how can we obtain the mirror across the diagonal?

For example, given the 3x2

```
U1 =

    11    12
    21    22
    31    32
```

matrix, how do we go about to get

```
U2=

    11    21
    12    31
    22    32
```

this matrix?

In the general case we seek to go from (where the two digits indicate the row/column indexes of each element-that is U_ij:=ij to make it clearer).

```
U =    11      12
       21      22
       31      32
       ... 
       (r-1)1  (r-1)2 
       r1      r2
```

to

```
V =   11        21
      12        31
      22        41
      ...       
      (r-2)2    r1
      (r-1)2    r2
```

I do understand that for a given row size, for example the one above where m=3, I could simply set `U2 = [U1(1,2) U1(2,1); U1(1,2) U1(3,2); U1(2,2) U1(3,2)]`, leaving the top left and bottom right elements unchanged while the others  exchange position in a diagonal manner, where the first column element exchanges place with the one on the second column and one position above it.. But I fail to do this dynamically when m varies.

I have tried using indexing and commands such as circshift and flip in combination but to no avail.

***NOTE***
If the given Matrix is square it is easy to see that the required matrix is the transpose which we get by
A = A' but the case I am studying is not so.

Comment: It's not clear how you're mathematically defining this "mirroring" for a non-square matrix, can you [edit] your question to include a (slightly) larger example, and ideally the algorithm you're using, even if just currently in your head, to achieve the expected output? For instance one might expect that `31` (bottom-left in `U1`) moves to the top-right in `U2` but that's not the case in your example

Comment: @Wolfie Thank you for the comment. I edited accordingly to make it clearer. In short, only the top left and bottom right elements remain the same. All else exchange position in a diagonal manner, where the first column element exchanges place with the one on the second column and one position above it.

Comment: Do you just want to move elements from one column to the other like `U(2:end, 1) = U(1:end-1, 2)` and similarly for the other column? Or am I not understanding it correctly?

Comment: Presumably `32` in your new `V` should be `41`?

Comment: @Wolfie Yes, corrected. Thanks for you time and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some 2-column matrix `A`, it looks like the output you want is

```
At = [[A(1,1); A(1:end-1,2)], [A(2:end,1); A(end,2)]];
```

Then we have

```
>> A =[11    12
       21    22
       31    32
       41    42];

>> At = [[A(1,1); A(1:end-1,2)], [A(2:end,1); A(end,2)]]
At =
    11    21
    12    31
    22    41
    32    42
```